# Beginner WPF/XML question: How to get an <element> in an <element>?

Tags: wpf, xml

I have a rather simple question. I'm trying to get information out of an XML file, and now I need to get the  that's inside another

This is my XML code:

```
<author>
  <name>Random_name1 (Random Name)</name>
  <uri>http://thisisanrandomurl.com</uri>
</author>
```

I can get the info with this code:

```
Name = item.Element(ns + "author").Value,
```

But this gives me:
"Random_name1 (Random Name) http://thisisanrandomurl.com"

I **only** want the info inside the   tags. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot,
- Niels

Comment: You say you "only want the info inside the tags". You would appear to be getting that. Can you be more specific about what you actually want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using LINQ to XML? Try:

```
Name = item.Element(ns + "author").Element(ns + "name").Value;
```

to get the data inside the 'name' element.  You can use `Elements` if there is more than one, and then use LINQ statements to select the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Xml;
```

After then please write this code

```
        XmlDocument myxml = new XmlDocument();

        myxml.Load("D:/sample.xml");//Load you xml file from you disk what you want to load

        string element_1 = myxml.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0].InnerText;
        string element_2 = myxml.GetElementsByTagName("uri")[0].InnerText;
```

Please try this it will be useful to you...